# How to connect page between signin,signup and profile in php

Tags: php, web

i'm still newbie in php, i want to connect this three page. I want to know how to tansfer data from signup to pfofile and also the sign in page. I tried to use  tag but not working.

page=signup

```
<body>
<?php
 // define variables and set to empty values
$email = $username = $name = $contact = $birthday = $gender = $address = $password = $payment           ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$contact = test_input($_POST["contact"]);
$birthday = test_input($_POST["birthday"]);
$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
$address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
$password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
$payment = test_input($_POST["payment"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
 }
 ?>
 <div id="login">
<form id="registeration" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<fieldset>
<legend><h1>Registeration</h1></legend>
 <p>Email:<br/>
 <input type="email" name="email"></p>
<p>Username:<br/>
  <input type="text" name="username" />
</p>
<p>Your Name:<br/>
<input type="text" name="name"/></p>
<p>Contact Number:<br/>
<input type="text" name="contact"/></p>
<p>Birthday:<br/>
 <input type="date" name="birthday">
 <p>Gender:<br/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
</p>
 <p>Address: <br/>
  <textarea name="address" cols="50"></textarea></p>  
<p>Password:<br/>
<input name="password" type="password" size="50"/></p>
</p>

<h2>Choose payment method:<br/></h2>
<p><input type="radio" name="payment" value="cod"/>CASH ON          DELIVERY</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Online Banking"/>ONLINE BANKING : CIMB Clicks<br/>
 <p><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Online Banking"/>ONLINE BANKING : Maybank<br/>
  <p><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Online Banking"/>ONLINE BANKING : BSN<br/>
<p><input type="radio" name="payment" value="atm"/>ATM</p>
<p><button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button><span>    <span><span><span><span>
   <button type="reset" value="cancel">Cancel</button></p>
</fieldset>
 </form> 
 </div>

echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $username;
echo "<br>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $contact;
echo "<br>";
echo $birthday;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
echo "<br>";
echo $address;
echo "<br>";
echo $password;
echo "<br>";
echo $payment;
    ?>

</body>
```

page=signin

```
<body>

<div id="login">
<fieldset>
 <legend><h1>Login</h1></legend>
 <form id="signin" method="POST">
 <p>Username:<br/>
 <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
 <p>Password:<br/>
 <input type="password" name="password"/></p>
 <p><button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button><span>
 <button type="reset" value="cancel">Cancel</button></p>
 </form>
 </fieldset>
 <!-- end .content --></div>
  <?php
        error_reporting(0);
        if (!empty ($_POST)){
        if ($_POST ["username"] == NULL){
            echo "Please insert your username!";}
            else{
                $strusername=$_POST["username"];
                echo "<p>$strusername</p>";
            }}
            if (!empty ($_POST)){
        if ($_POST ["password"] == NULL){
            echo "Please insert the password!";}
            else {
                $strpassword=$_POST["password"];
                echo "<p>$strpassword</p>";
            }}
    ?>
        </body>
```

page=profile

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<table>
<td colspan="5"><b>PROFILE</b></td>
 <tr>
<td><div align="left">Username:</div></td><td><?php echo $username ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">Name:</div></td><td><?php echo $name ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">Username:</div></td><td><?php echo $username ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">Birthday:</div></td><td><?php echo $birthday ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">Contact Number:</div></td><td><?php echo $contact ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">Gender:</div></td><td><?php echo $gender ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">Address:</div></td><td><?php echo $address ?></td></tr>
<td><div align="left">My payment Method:</div></td><td><?php echo $payment ?></td>          </tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="left"><button type="submit" value="Edit Profile" >Edit Profile</button></div>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
 <!-- end .content --></div>
 <!-- end .container --></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: try making SESSION..

Answer (score 0):

Well, Try to use the post and get.

The PHP superglobals $_GET and $_POST are used to collect form-data.The example below displays a simple HTML form with two input fields and a submit button:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When the user fills out the form above and clicks the submit button, the form data is sent for processing to a PHP file named "welcome.php". The form data is sent with the HTTP POST method.

To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables. The "welcome.php" looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The output could be something like this:

```
Welcome John
Your email address is john.doe@example.com
```

The same result could also be achieved using the HTTP GET method:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and "welcome_get.php" looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I Suggest you to follow this tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
I hope it will help you, best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION

In every page start with `<?php session_start(); ?>`

then store `$_SESSION['email'] = test_input($_POST["email"]);`

Then in any page you can use `echo $_SESSION['email'];`

Answer (score 0):

You should use SESSION for simple login functionality....

refer this [tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/php-login-page-example.html) about basic login and functionality